# Ring homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$ where $a^2=a$ but $a\neq\phi(1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$. Prove if $\phi(1)=a$ then $a^2=a$. Give an example to show the converse is false.

The first part I found easy enough.
$$a^2=\phi(1)^2=\phi(1^2)=a$$
Now I have trouble to negate the converse. Here is the initial statement:
$$\forall\phi:Z_m\rightarrow Z_n,\quad\forall a\in Z_n,\quad\phi(1)=a\implies a^2=a\tag{1}$$
Converse of $(1)$:
$$\forall\phi:Z_m\rightarrow Z_n,\quad\forall a\in Z_n,\quad a^2=a\implies\phi(1)=a\tag{2}$$
Negation of $(2)$:
$$\exists\phi:Z_m\rightarrow Z_n,\quad\exists a\in Z_n,\quad a^2=a\land\phi(1)\neq a\tag{3}$$
which is what we prove.

- Choose the homomorphism $\phi:x\mapsto x\cdot1$.
- $\phi(1)=1$.
- Choose $a=0=0^2$.

We have negated $(3)$. Yeah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the trivial ring homomorphism $\phi$ : $\mathbb{Z}$/$6 \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$/$6 \mathbb{Z}$; $x \mapsto x$

Now let $t = 3 \mod 6$ (an element in $\mathbb{Z}$/$6 \mathbb{Z}$)

Observe: $t^2 = 9 \mod 6 = 3 \mod 6 = t$

Also observe that $\phi(1) = 1 \mod 6$, which does not equal $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}$/$6 \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus we are done with this example.

N.B:

.  $\phi(a+b) = a + b \mod 6 = (a \mod 6) + (b \mod 6) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$

.  and  $\phi(ab) = ab \mod 6 = (a \mod 6)(b \mod 6) = \phi(a) \phi(b)$

.  with clearly $\phi(1) = 1 \mod 6$ (the identity element)

$\implies \phi$ is a ring homomorphism

Comment: First, please use mathjax for a readable typesetting. Second, $\phi(1) = 1$, not $3$, as you wrongly stated.

Comment: Thank you for the correction; have edited @Didier . Will update w/ type setting later

Comment: For instance, use `$a = 3 \mod 6$` to get $a=3 \mod 6$ (or `$a = 3 \pmod 6$` to get $a = 3 \pmod 6$), `$\phi(1)$` to get $\phi(1)$, and `$a^2$` to get $a^2$. For a fancy Z, use `$\mathbb{Z}$` to get $\mathbb{Z}$. (no need to surround each item itself, just the whole equation: `$a + b = c$` instead of `$a$ + $b$ = $c$`. See [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the advice; pretty sure there is nothing extra I would add to it now.. this is my first answer on here, so thanks for the coaching! @Didier

Comment: You're welcome, and very welcome on this website!